# Jersey and JSON

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I 'Ve built a REST Webservice in JAVA using jersey.
Everything was working fine until I switched the MediaType from application_xml to application_json.

If I am using XML then everything works as it should:

**clientside:**

```
public static CoResponse rO = new CoResponse();

rO = service.path("check-in").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(CoResponse.class,  rO);
```

**serverside:**

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public CoResponse newCheckin(JAXBElement<CoResponse> obj){
    CoResponse newObj = obj.getValue();
    //DO SOMETHING....
    return newObj
}
```

When i change the MediaType to Application_JSON i'am getting a 415 unsupported type error:

**clientside:**

```
public static CoResponse rO = new CoResponse();
rO = service.path("check-in").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(CoResponse.class,  rO);
```

**serverside:**

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CoResponse newCheckin(JAXBElement<CoResponse> obj){
    CoResponse newObj = obj.getValue();
    //DO SOMETHING....
    return newObj
}
```

Is there something else to do when using JSON?
thank you.

---

**The classes I used are as follows:**

CoResponse object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CoResponse {

    private int code;
    private String errorMessage;

    //Datastore
    public CoDataList<CoDataMap<String, String>> data = new CoDataList<CoDataMap<String, String>>();
}
```

CoDataList Object:

```
public class CoDataList <V> implements Map<Integer, V>{
    int nextIndex;

    public Map<Integer, V> data = new HashMap<Integer,V>();

}
```

CoDataMap Object:

```
public class CoDataMap <K, V> implements Map<K, V>{ 
    public Map<K, V> data = new HashMap<K,V>();
}
```

Comment: any errors in your app server logs?

Comment: no, no server logs. The error appears on client side and the server doenst even go into the post method.  I dont need the Jaxb, i could also use CoResponse directly. But it doesnt change anything. Error still appears

Comment: I assume that there are some additional methods implemented for the "Map" in CoDataMap and CoDataList to fully implements on the interface, correct?

Comment: yes of course.  Didn't post it to reduce the size of the post. But only the methods to override the map interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to fix my problem just by calling the following method within the response call:

```
.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
```

Everything I changed was the init-params in the web.xml and client side as Spencer-Kormos suggested and adding the above line to the call.

Now the Client side looks as follows:

```
rO = service.path("check-in")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .put(CoResponse.class, rO);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a init-param for JSON POJO support to the web.xml configuration for Jersey:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section

Comment: Thank you, thats probably something I forgot but it didnt solved my problem. Any other sugesstions?

Comment: Are you using the JAXB annotations on your entity object?

Comment: Yes but only @XMLRootElement. It's working fine with Application_Xml. Do i need any other annotations if using json instead of xml?

Comment: i've added the objects to my post. May be it's easier then.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, add @Produces annotation:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CoResponse newCheckin(JAXBElement<CoResponse> obj){
}
```